# Meaning of liminf of sets

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I've been struggling for a while to understand the meaning of liminf of a sequence of sets.

I know that the definition is

$\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n:=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{m\geq n} A_n$.

When I break it up into pieces, I get $(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap \ldots) \cup (A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \ldots) \cup (A_3 \cap A_4 \cap \dots) \cup (A_4 \cap \ldots) \cup \ldots$.

Here, $A_n$ occurs infinitely many times, doesn't it? Because it is in each set of parentheses?

Or do the unions mean **OR**, so that $A_n$ might or might not be in any of the sets?

However, this is wrong! Why? I'm confused.

Comment: Note that in your shortened notation, the sets in the intersection should be indexed $m$ rather than $n$. In the expressed notation, though, things are okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the definition slightly wrong: It should be $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n:=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{m\geq n} A_m$$
(the difference being the index at the end).

Now any given $A_k$ occurs in only finitely many of the infinite unions $\bigcap_{m\geq n} A_m$, namely for $n\le k$.

The reason this is called the liminf is that you may think of $B_n=\bigcap_{m\geq n} A_m$ as being the infimum of the sets $A_n$, $A_{n+1}$, … as it is the largest set contained in each of them. And now the sets $B_1$, $B_2$, … form an increasing sequence of sets, so the “limit” of this sequence will be their union.

And yes, union means “or”. An infinite union becomes an infinitely big “or”, so being a member of the union means being a member of at least one of the sets. You will find that $x$ belongs to $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{m\geq n} A_m$ if and only if it is in $\bigcap_{m\geq n} A_m$ for at least some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which means it is in every $A_m$ for $m$ larger than some $n$. (In short, “for every sufficiently large $m$”.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is great, except it would be better if you could use numbers instead of letters (e.g. provide a concrete example along the lines of my long notation? Then I could understand this better.)

Comment: Maybe it would be better, but I haven't got the time right now. I suggest you look at $A_3$ and notice how it appears in only they first three of your infinite unions. Then think about how that generalizes to $A_4$, $A_5$, or indeed $A_k$ for some $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it up.  Define:
$$
B_n=A_n\cap A_{n+1}\cap A_{n+2}\cap\ldots
$$
Then you've got $B_1\cup B_2\cup\ldots$  Now, $B_n$ is all the elements that live in all $A_i$ for $i\geq n$.  By taking a union you can maybe convince yourself that the limit infimum is the set of all elements that are in all but finitely many $A_i$.